# executing SQL query with temp tables using 1.6jdk

Tags: sql-server, java, jdbc, temporary-tables, prepared-statement

I created a batch to run a query that has temp tables as the below example

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TEMP1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
select * 
into #TEMP1
from cutomer

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP2
select *
into #TEMP2 
from shops

select t1.*
from #TEMP1 t1, #TEMP2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id
```

I am using the Java code below:

```
PreparedStatement statment = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery();
```

It is working fine when I use 1.8 JRE, but it is throwing the following exception with 1.6 and I have to use 1.6. I am using sqljdbc4.jar only.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Probably could just add a Return 1; to the end of your query batch.

Just a guess out of the dark based on the error message. (I haven't touched Java in a while, but I'd bet they changed the way that method works between JRE versions.)

Comment: I got the below error when I run the query using dbvisualizer after adding return 1; at the end of the query[Code: 178, SQL State: S1000]  A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Comment: Yea, sorry my guess was shotty at best and it was late when I was reading through this question. Re-reading it now, I don't think this is the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of the SQL statement. I've just solved a similar issue of no result set return. Problem solved after adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` .